# Routing based on dynamo id in React and aws

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm using react router dom to create routes to individual records in a dynamo table. So in order to accomplish this, I created a table listing all records and was able to filter these through the following route in order to get individual records.

```
<Route  path="/PatientFilter/:patientId" component={({match}) => <Filter patientId={match.params.patientId}/> }/>
```

now that is good and fine. My problem or rather question is whether its possible for me to somehow save the patientId returned from the individual record for other routes without having to make a new appsync query to handle this new case.
Thanks!

Comment: The `patientId` is parth of your route, what do you mean with your `appsync query` What is the problem you are trying to handle?